# Joining multiple SQL queries to display online friends list?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to join 3 tables together to display a list of table `users` taken from table `subscribers` only where their IP = an IP in table `online`.

`subscribers` table: (Doesn't allow duplicates, `type` tells if or not the other user is subscribed back.)

```
sender  recipient
1       5     
5       3
```

`users` table:

```
id  loginip
1   192.168.0.1
3   192.168.0.2
5   192.168.0.3
```

`online` table:

```
ip
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.5
```

So the query should grab the `id`'s, find the `loginip` of the `id`'s and then scan the `online` table and return online users: (Assuming UserID = 5)

```
sender  recipient  send_ip       reci_ip
5       3          192.168.0.3   192.168.0.2
1       5          192.168.0.1   192.168.0.3
```

I also need to figure out a way to cut the IP if user = 5, so it does not display yourself on the list. I can probably do that myself after one of you fine people help me out a bit. :)

My attempt, although very poor:

```
SELECT  f.sender as friend1,
    f.recipient as friend2,
    u1.loginip ip1,
    u2.loginip ip2
FROM subscribers f
INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = f.sender
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = f.recipient
INNER JOIN online o1 ON o1.ip = u1.loginip
INNER JOIN online o2 ON o2.ip = u2.loginip
WHERE 
    f.sender = 5 OR 
    f.recipient = 5;
```

Thank you.

UPDATE: I must be very tired, because it suddenly works? I'm so sorry.

Comment: what are you planning to do with the people using multiple ip's or the single ip used by multiple people

Comment: Their IP updates as they log in, and the online row deletes after 15 minutes of inactivity. I'm going to add an identifier later to solve those issues.

Comment: What is missing from your query? Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Let's say userID=1 logs in, it then drags in ALL rows with his IP due to the multiple INNER JOIN's even if the other person is not online. I do not have much experience with Joining queries so I'm stuck.

Comment: You're using `INNER JOINS` (and rightfully so). They will filter out records where either of the two are not online.

Comment: The problem comes when only one of them is online, it says that both of them are.

Comment: Here's SQL Fiddle with your data and code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0e16/1  Please create the scenario you're describing and post back the link.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42d4d3/1/0 - It works almost fine here, it's just that when userID 5 is online, because his IP is either going to be a recipient or a sender IP, it outputs the row. I need it to not output a row if the IP is equal to the IP of the user in the WHERE clause. I'm at a standstill.

Comment: I still do not understand the problem.  You will **not** have a row where both users are not on-line.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b70a7/1 - User 3 is no longer on line and his record is gone though user 5 is online.

Comment: ^ I know I've just realized how stupid I've been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is contained in the question. I'm posting it just so that the question doesn't appear to be unanswered.

```
SELECT  f.sender as friend1,
    f.recipient as friend2,
    u1.loginip ip1,
    u2.loginip ip2
FROM subscribers f
INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = f.sender
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = f.recipient
INNER JOIN online o1 ON o1.ip = u1.loginip
INNER JOIN online o2 ON o2.ip = u2.loginip
WHERE 
    f.sender = 5 OR 
    f.recipient = 5;
```